# How can I get the intersection of three shapes colliding and delete the parts that are not colliding in KonvaJs?

Tags: konvajs, react-konva, konva, konvajs-reactjs

If I am given 3 circles and they are positioned as the [primary colors circles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2ie2.png) (3 circles intersecting each other), is there a function that might help me to delete the parts that are not colliding with anything and just keep the intersecting parts?

Another example could be drawing three lines in such a way that it forms a triangle. By deleting the parts that are not colliding, we would end up with 3 points (at least visually, not sure if I end up with 3 in total or 6 from stacking up), which are the edges of the previous triangle.

I have been checking the [ClipFunc](https://konvajs.org/docs/clipping/Clipping_Function.html) and the [HitFunc](https://konvajs.org/docs/events/Custom_Hit_Region.html), but I am not sure if I am going through the correct/best path to solving my problem.